# what does " calculus" mean when used in logic? and more broadly in mathematics? ( not a question dealing specially with derivatives, integrals, etc.)

Tags: logic, foundations, philosophy

Sentence logic is sometimes called " propositional calculus".

I'd be interested in knowing what the word " calculus" means precisely/ technically here, and what are the ( historical) roots of this use of the word " calculus".

As a pure hypothesis, I would say that any system of objects could be called a "calculus" provided :

(1) there are some operations defined for these objects

(2) these operations are purely extensional, that is, all extensionnaly equivalent expressions can be substituted for one another *salva veritate*

Is there a link, as I suppose, between " calculus" and extensionality?

Is it possible to give an example of a mathematical system that  *cannot* be called a " calculus"?

Comment: Originally, a calculus is a pebble.  Romans used pebbles on a string (an abacus) or on a counting board to "calculate."  To my knowledge, propositional calculus bears no connection to analytic calculus (more commonly just calculus).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I don't think it has a precise meaning; "concrete set of rules for manipulating syntactic expressions" is close to the best thing I can think of. Of course, it's both  vague and broad.

---

That said, we usually speak of (logical) calculi in the context of a fixed semantics for our language, in which case we're interested in calculi which are [*sound* and *complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) with respect to that semantics. In this case, for various meanings of the word "concrete," we can indeed rule out the existence of calculi for various logics. [**Second-order logic**](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) (with the standard semantics) is a prime example, since basic questions about its entailment relation are set-theoretically contingent - e.g. there is a sentence $\varphi$ in second-order logic which is true in every structure, hence entailed by $\top$, iff the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) holds.

And then there are logics which are intermediate. For example, no non-compact logic has a finitary proof system, so in that sense doesn't have a calculus; however, some non-compact logics - the prime example being the [infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/), which indeed satisfies [a technical analogue of compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barwise_compactness_theorem) - do still have very well-behaved "infinitary" proof systems. Do these count as calculi?

Answer (score 4):

"Calculus" in this sense is not really a technical term.  The OED says
"A system or method of calculation, ‘a certain way of performing mathematical investigations and resolutions’ (Hutton); a branch of mathematics involving or leading to calculations, as the differential, integral calculus, etc. The differential calculus is often spoken of as ‘the calculus’."

See [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html)

Comment: From the OP: "and more broadly in mathematics?"

Comment: Whoops, my reading comprehension is *great*.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Tanks for this interesting link.